# Etiqueta html para seleccionar una parte de texto y aplicar estilos

Tags: html, css

Hola estoy tratando de aplicar estilos con CSS a unos trozos de un párrafo y necesito dividirlo en partes pequeñas y no se como se llama la etiqueta para hacer eso.

```
<p>

<trozo id="trozo_1"> parte de ejemplo </trozo>
el párrafo continua normal con su respectivo estilo
<trozo id="trozo_2"> otra parte de ejemplo</trozo>
el párrafo continua normal nuevamente

</p>
```

La intención de tener una etiqueta que divida el texto es para hacer referencia desde un CSS

```
#trozo_1{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#trozo_2{
    color: green;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

Comment: puedes usar la etiqueta span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la etiqueta `span` puedes realizarlo

```css
#span_1 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#span_2 {
    color: green;
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <span id="span_1"> parte de ejemplo </span>
    el párrafo continua normal con su respectivo estilo
    <span id="span_2"> otra parte de ejemplo</span>
    el párrafo continua normal nuevamente
</p>
```